# Creating graph class

Tags: python, graph, networkx

How can i draw new class called flow graph. I got a lot of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Graphs.py", line 26, in <module>
    nx.draw(F1)
  File "/home/thinkpad/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py", line 131, in draw
    draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, ax=ax, **kwds)
  File "/home/thinkpad/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py", line 262, in draw_networkx
    pos = nx.drawing.spring_layout(G)  # default to spring layout
  File "/home/thinkpad/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/networkx/drawing/layout.py", line 232, in fruchterman_reingold_layout
    if len(G)==0:
TypeError: object of type 'FlowGraph' has no len()
```

The code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class FlowGraph:
    G=nx.DiGraph()
    I=[]
    O=[]

F1=FlowGraph()
# Add nodes
F1.G.add_node(1)
F1.G.add_node(2)
F1.G.add_node(3) 
# Add edges
F1.G.add_edge(1,2)
#F1.G.add_edges_from[(1,2),(2,3)]
# Add interface
F1.I=[1]
F1.O=[3]
nx.draw(F1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: How can i change the code to obtain nice sketch of my graph :)

Comment: can you edit the question to say what kind of graph you want to draw. This is very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback tells you that the function `nx.draw` has failed. If you look at the docstring of `nx.draw` you will see that it expects a **networkx graph** as a first argument. Instead, you've provided it a `FlowGraph` instance. The function `nx.draw` simply doesn't know what to do with your `FlowGraph`.

Perhaps you wish to pass `F1.G` into `nx.draw`? Note that `F1.G` is a **networkx graph**.